# How to prove that this is a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Right now I am struggling as to how to approach this question my lecturer was very poor at conveying this topic.
So here's the question that I am facing with:
If V is any vector space and $ \mathbb c $ is scalar, let $ \mathbb T:V\rightarrow V$ be the function defined by $ \mathbb T(v) =cv$.
a)Show that T is a linear operator(it is called the scalar transformation by $ \mathbb c $).
b)For $V =\mathbb R^2$ sketch $ \mathbb T(1,0)$ and $\mathbb T(0,1)$ in the following cases:
 (i) $ \mathbb c=2$; (ii) $ \mathbb c=\frac{1}{2}$; (iii) $ \mathbb c=-1$;

Comment: What *exactly* you don't understand? You know what a *linear operator* is, right? If yo do, then check the given $\;T\;$ is a linear operator, and if you don't then read it elsewhere as it is a very important, basic and elementary notion in lionear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that $T(\lambda v+\mu w)=\lambda T(v)+\mu T(w)$ for all $v,w\in V$ and $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{F}$. Here $\mathbb{F}$ is the base field. In most cases one considers $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Now by defintion there is some $c\in \mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v)=cv$ for all $v\in V$. Hence $$T(\lambda v +\mu w)=c(\lambda v +\mu w)=\lambda(cv)+\mu(cw)=\lambda T(v)+\lambda T(w).$$ 
This shows that $T$ is linear. Notice that a linear map can be described as a map that preserves linear combinations of vectors. If you understand this last sentence, you will never forget what a linear map is.

Now do $b)$ yourself.

Comment: Can you just tell me if I'm going right so I said $ \mathbb T(v)=cv $  So for (i) I did $ \mathbb T(1,0) =2v $ and got (2,0) as my answer similarly I did it for $ \mathbb T(0,1)=(0,2) $ So do I sketch these points as my answer.

Comment: That's right, although you should think of $(0,1)$ as the arrow pointing from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$. Applying $T$ to this arrow (with $c=2$) doubles the length of this arrow. In fact that is what $T$ does, it doubles lengths but preserves dirctions.